# Assembly (emu8086) reverse decimal text

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm having struggle with assembly. At the moment I'm just an beginner and I finished one task at the moment, however now I'm struggling with input of decimal text and output it reverse. I searched trough answers and I noticed this code part:

```
DATA SEGMENT
    MSG1 DB 10,13,'input: $'
    MSG2 DB 10,13,'output reverse: $' 

    P1 LABEL BYTE
    M1 DB 0FFH
    L1 DB ?
    P11 DB 0FFH DUP ('$')
    P22 DB 0FFH DUP ('$')

DATA ENDS
DISPLAY MACRO MSG
    MOV AH,9
    LEA DX,MSG
    INT 21H
ENDM   
CODE SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA
START:
        MOV AX,DATA
        MOV DS,AX                

        DISPLAY MSG1

        LEA DX,P1
        MOV AH,0AH    
        INT 21H

        DISPLAY MSG2

        LEA SI,P11
        LEA DI,P22

        MOV DL,L1
        DEC DL
        MOV DH,0
        ADD SI,DX
        MOV CL,L1
        MOV CH,0

REVERSE:
        MOV AL,[SI]
        MOV [DI],AL
        INC DI
        DEC SI
        LOOP REVERSE

        DISPLAY P22

        LEA SI,P11
        LEA DI,P22   

        MOV CL,L1
        MOV CH,0

        MOV AH,4CH
        INT 21H
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Program works perfectly, but how to make input into RAM with my wanted text in decimal?

For example I want to type name: John which is 74 111 104 110 in decimal and I'm stucked.

P.S. Could you also recommend me more assembly guides, where to find these kind of type tasks like convert your word into decimal/binary, outputs etc.

Comment: I think I only input my decimal here:
DATA SEGMENT
    MSG1 DB 10,13,'input: $' <-------------
    MSG2 DB 10,13,'output reverse: $' <-------------

Instead of MSG1 DB I should put decimal text?

Comment: Push it on the stack then pop and output it.

Comment: Doesn't work.
I tried to change some data, but still it doesn't read my decimal. Instead of an input I need write decimal and get it reversed. Still working on it :|

Comment: And also even if it outputs what I want I can't see my outputted text in memory.

Comment: OK, think I get it. "Beginner", "Decimal" and "Assembly" don't go together well. Therefore I suggest you switch to ASCII then HEX input format. Once you have those working start thinking about Decimal <-> Hex conversion, which is not trivial in assembly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what this question (which is apparently about PC programming) has to do with EE...?

Comment: Usually in DOS, when using BIOS/DOS services, the input from keyboard is character/string, i.e. ASCII encoded. So input "74 111" is already 6 bytes long with values 0x37, 0x34, 0x20, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31 ... and your code has to parse that, validate what is digit and whatnot, and convert single successive digits into single integer value (like `temp=temp*10 + digit_char - '0'` until non-digit char is read). Then putting that integer value, like "74" into memory as single byte and passing that to DOS services as ASCII encoded character is enough to display 'J' on screen.

Comment: For more guides and info, you may want to check "info" of x86 tag here at stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info ... and also do some check of questions, there is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emu8086 tag here, see where other people were struggling and what was answered to them (SO is full of common questions to the point, that you may get rejected quickly as "duplicate" or "too broad" by people who read it regularly, and have seen your type of problem for 100 time this year, so doing first some search to avoid plain duplicates can be better in the end).